# How can I return msword file data in Python / Flask to render in iframe or embed it to preview?

Tags: python, flask, get, jinja2, mime-types

I am trying to render (get previewed) a stored Word or PDF file in HTML from project directory.

For example, I have a user who has his resume stored in his account. Now I want to give him a preview of his resume in his account page. It can be doc, docx or pdf. How can I return msword or pdf data in Python/Flask so that it can be rendered in HTML / Jinja2 either in iframe or embeded. Here is my code

```
from flask import render_template, url_for, flash, redirect, request, abort, jsonify,session, send_file
import os
import mimetypes

@app.route("/account", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def account():

    resume = current_user.resume
    resumefile = downloadresume()
    return render_template('account.html', pagetitle='Account', profile_pic=profile_pic, form=form, resume=resume, resumefile = resumefile)

@app.route("/account/downloadresume", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def downloadresume():
    filename = current_user.resume
    mime = mimetypes.MimeTypes().guess_type(filename)[0] 
    if mime in ["application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document","application/msword"]:
        # return filename.data
        return send_file(resume.data, as_attachment=False)
```

## Jinja / HTML

```
<iframe src="{{ resumefile }}"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure about Word documents, but I know the [PDFjs](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js) library will be able to load a PDF and render it into a canvas.

An example of its usage can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/pdfjs/9engc9mw/

```js
// If absolute URL from the remote server is provided, configure the CORS
// header on that server.
var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ba2edeae/examples/learning/helloworld.pdf';

// Loaded via <script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.
var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

// The workerSrc property shall be specified.
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

// Asynchronous download of PDF
var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);
loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
  console.log('PDF loaded');
  
  // Fetch the first page
  var pageNumber = 1;
  pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
    console.log('Page loaded');
    
    var scale = 1.5;
    var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});

    // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
    var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    // Render PDF page into canvas context
    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
    renderTask.promise.then(function () {
      console.log('Page rendered');
    });
  });
}, function (reason) {
  // PDF loading error
  console.error(reason);
});
```

```css
#the-canvas {
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>

<h1>PDF.js 'Hello, world!' example</h1>

<canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
```

Since it's done in the frontend, you'll just need to make sure the PDF file is accessible. With Word files, I'm sure you can convert them to PDF, however you may lose some functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible ways to this. You do not have a single method to render pdf and docx files.

**For pdf files:**

- You can either use the method stated by @MichaelBauer or place a hyperlink which points to the pdf file in a directory. All current browsers have the capability to render pdf files from any offline or online directory.

**For docx files**

- You have to convert the docx file to a pdf file so that rendering becomes easier. And then follow the process of rendering the converted pdf. As for converting a pdf to docx seamlessly, you have Adobe's Document Cloud SDK service.